# How do I filter a to do list in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

everyone. New to asking questions here, although I use it to find answers pretty frequently. My issue is this:

I have a "to do list" application. I'm able to add, delete, and mark to do items complete. However, what I'm struggling with is the filter for viewing the different items (view all, only active, and only completed).

I have everything built around the buttons and the click event, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to actually display the desired to do items. Clicking the buttons returns an error that todo.filter is not a function, so I'm apparently off in left field somewhere with my current solution.

Here is the code I'm using to try to filter the array and show only the to do items with the boolean completed: true.

```
filComplete = id => {
this.setState({
  todos: this.state.todos.map(todo => {
    let comTodo = todo.filter(todo => todo.completed = true);
    return comTodo;
  })      
})
}
```

From my own understanding, I am mapping all of the todo items where completed is true to a new array for display, but I'm obviously not doing something right.

todo is each individual todo item.
todos is the array of todo items.
id is the key of todo.id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only `filter` instead of `map`.

Comment: `=` is assignment.

Comment: A view filter should not be modifying anything in state, to begin with.

Comment: To clarify, `todo.filter(todo => todo.completed);` should work.  No need for map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let comTodo = todo.filter(todo => todo.completed = true);
```

Using a single `=` is an assignment, not a comparison.  Instead, you can just use

```
let comTodo = todo.filter(todo => todo.completed);
```

if completed is a Boolean.  You also don't need to combine `map` with `filter` if all you want is simple filtering, so the final production would look like

```
filComplete = id => {
  this.setState({
    todos: this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with `map` - that just transforms an array to another of the same length. Just use `filter` to check the `completed` property and remove those incomplete todos:

```
this.setState({
  todos: this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed)
});
```

Although note that doing this means that, once you're only showing the completed todos, you can't recover the full list. You probably want the full list in your props, not state.

One other potential problem with this is that `setState` is asynchronous, and therefore doesn't always work correctly when you reference `this.state` inside it - as that won't always have the value you expect. Instead, pass in function which describes how to transform the old state to the new:

```
this.setState(state => ({
  todos: state.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed)
}));
```

Comment: you're absolutely right. This does what I want it to as far as filtering my list, but every time it's filtered, the previous data is lost. When you say add the list to props instead of state, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean that since, as you've observed, your component has no access to the original list of todos, once the filtering has been done, you will need to keep the original list in the component's props, rather than state. (As these are the only two places React components can store data which is relevant for rendering.) Exactly how you do this depends on how your overall application is put together - but somewhere you will need to keep the complete list, even if you filter it in a child component. There are loads of React todo list examples you could look to for inspiration.